# callcc -- Call-with-current-continuation

Tags: ruby

I've start getting acquainted with Ruby and met a function never seen before -- `callcc`.
I've understood some general idea of what's it for but when i had tried to write an example and i've got unexpected result.

```
require 'continuation'
def callcc_func
  i = 0
  while true
    c = nil
    callcc {|x| c = x}
    i += 1
    puts i    
    return c if (i % 3) == 0
  end
end

c = callcc_func()
puts
callcc_func.call
```

The result is an endless loop. Why?
I've expected it to be:

```
# for `c = callcc_func()` line
1
2
3

# callcc_func.call
4
5
6
#end here because of `return c if (i % 3) == 0`
```

*P.S.*
Sorry for my English and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call-with-current-continuation` (generally abbreviated as `call/cc` originated in Scheme, so if you want to know more about it, Scheme docs are a good starting point:

- [call/cc in the Racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-current-continuation%29%29)
- [call/cc on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation)

As for your Ruby problem: look at this blog post title [Continuations and ruby](http://blog.mostof.it/continuations-and-ruby/#.T7N7DHktiWU), it implements something very similar to what you are trying to do. You'll find an explanation there:

> As a script file run by the main ruby interpreter, this will loop
>   forerver as it captures the control state of the program when and
>   where it was called and this includes returning the continuation and
>   then calling it again.

Comment: I wonder if there's any task callcc is the logically right solution for. Thank you.

Comment: @ted The Seaside web framework in Smalltalk uses continuations for tracking the state of web applications, as does Wee for Ruby (a discontinued project though).

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a bit late but maybe someone will be interested in.

You can fix your code just by changing last line of your code to:

```
c.call
```

One of the applicance of this feature is making generators. Here's sample random numbers generator (constants taken from Numerical Recipies book):

```
def randomLCG(a,m,c,seed)
    initialized = false
    while true
        callcc {|x| $cc = x}
        if not initialized
            initialized = true
            return
        end
        seed = (a*seed + c) % m;
        return seed
    end
end
```

And usage:

```
> randomLCG( 1664525, 2147483647 , 1013904223, 107 )
 => nil 
> $cc.call
 => 1192008398 
> $cc.call
 => 2079128816 
> $cc.call
 => 667419302
```

In Python we would probably use keyword `yield` to meet the same goal (please notice that in Ruby keyword `yield` does different thing):

```
def randLCG (a , m , c , seed):
    while True:
        seed = ( a∗seed + c ) % m
        yield seed
```

Usage:

```
>>> random = randLCG ( 1664525 , 2147483647 , 1013904223, 107 ) 
>>> random
<generator object randLCG at 0x7fdc790f70a0>
>>> random.next()
1192008398
>>> random.next()
2079128816
>>> random.next()
667419302
```

Ofc in Ruby ofc you can use closures to that problem so your program will be shorter:

```
require 'continuation'

def rand(a, m, c, seed)
    return lambda{ seed = (a*seed + c) % m; return seed }
end

c = rand( 1664525, 2147483647 , 1013904223, 107 )
c.call
c.call
```

The second usage that comes to my mind is implementing [`mutual recursions`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).